# NoSuchElementException error after working for a few pages selenium script

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I was wondering if there is anyway to protect a script from breaking before it exits due to NoSuchElementException error. My script works for the first few pages on the website and is able to find the element but after those first few it exits due to no such element error. I was wondering how I could keep the program from exiting and get through to the end of the pages. Sorry I am new to stack overflow so I don't if I am asking correctly. Thanks!

```
line 39, in <module>
    main3 = main.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-content-column"]/div/div[7]/div/div[2]/div/div/ng-transclude/table/tbody')


 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="main-content-column"]/div/div[7]/div/div[2]/div/div/ng-transclude/table/tbody"}
```

Comment: Add html page you test or link to it

Comment: You could use a `while` loop and inside do a `try` and `except` so that each time it breaks it just starts over

Answer (score 0):

Not all elements have the same Xpath or Css. Try to see when it fails - maybe the element has another expression.

Also, try to use this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, secondsToWait); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id(elementID)));
```

There are many ExpectedConditions like elementToBeClickable, elementToBeVissible and so on.